# How to take backup of file without changing its time-stamp with Ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible, backup, devops

How to take backup of file **without changing its time-stamp** with Ansible playbook? I tried `backup=yes` but the problem is like it changes the timestamp os the file. 
Code:- `dest={{item}} state=absent regexp='TLSv1' backup=yes`   `with_items: ('{{certs_dir.stdout_lines}}')`

Comment: Please post your code snippet.

Comment: `lineinfile: dest={{item}} state=absent regexp='TLSv1' backup=yes `                                      
   `with_items: certs_dir.stdout_lines`

Comment: put the code in your question, not as a comment

Answer (score -1):

I'm retracting my initial "It can't be done" response - it should be possible by using a series of plays, but it's not very pretty.

If you really need the backup file to keep the time-stamp, you might want to put in an official request on the developer mailing list.

1. Use the `stat` module on the initial file to retrieve the file timestamp
2. Register the backup file name in the return value `backup_file` from the `file` or `copy` module.
3. Use the `command` module to call the `touch` command to set the time of the backup_file to the original time.  (The Ansible `stat` module does not adjust file timestamps.)